# Do Electronic Viewfinders Record Data?

Tags: digital, image-processing, viewfinder, android, electronics

I saw this post:

[How does an electronic viewfinder work?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/how-does-an-electronic-viewfinder-work)

But I am more interested if the electronic viewfinder on a digital camera or smartphone saves image data before it is captured and written to storage, or is it more of a RAM-like situation where the data would only held temporarily and instantly re-written with the next frame?

Edit: On smartphones meaning when either the camera app is open or when an app that uses the camera is opened.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A digital photo is not a "snapshot" taken from the electronic viewfinder. A digital photo is read directly from the sensor. The electronic viewfinder is fed with basically a video feed from the sensor too of course, but it is just displayed there, not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Electronic viewfinder is just a display which represent the data, captured from sensor. It is memory (and processor) only operation. When you instruct the camera/phone to take the image it get it from the sensor and store it in non-volative storage (SD card, flash memory, etc)